# Displaying a text field along with radio through Django form

Tags: django, forms, django-models, django-forms

Lets say I have a model with 2 fields. With one field being a choice field of radio button Choice1, Choice2 and Other, the next being Other which is a textfield I want the "other" textbox to appar / enabled only when "Other" is selected in the radio button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is not from the django-forms category. This applies more to the front-end category. Everything that is sent from the django server is static. Sure, you can write a form class and override the template for it. Also, you can connect the js script directly to the form class. It is convenient, but not canonical. Just, write the JS script or using JQuery, which will activate the field when you select a particular option.
I wrote for you a small example of how this can be do it.
I hope this helps you.

```js
$('input[type=radio][name=choices]').change(function() {
 $('input[type=text][name=other]').prop(
   'disabled',
    function(i, v) {
     return !v;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <p><input name="choices" type="radio" value="choice1">Choice 1</p>
  <p><input name="choices" type="radio" value="choice2">Choice 2</p>
  <p><input name="other" type="text" disabled></p>
</form>
```